# Como de fazer o js esperar uma ação de uma classe criada por ele

Tags: javascript, modal, onclick

Fiz um código para que o js crie uma div sempre que o usuário clica em um botão. E eu gostaria que quando o usuário clicar nessa div apareça um modal, com formulário para preencher.
Porém sempre da o mesmo erro,

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
Sendo porque quando eu vou pegar a classe da div, o js não entende mesmo a classe existindo

Fiz uns testes, e quando eu já deixo essa div pré feita no html, o modal funciona (porém somente o modal criado pelo html), sendo exatamente o mesmo código que o js gera ao clicar no botão.

Segue o código:

```js
function abreModalInfo(modalid) {
    const modal = document.getElementById(modalid);
    modal.classList.add('mostrar');
}


const infoLivro = document.querySelector('.infoLivro'); //Já tentei com getElementByClassName também
infoLivro.addEventListener('click', () => abreModalInfo('modalInfoLivro'));
```

```js
let imgInfo = document.createElement('img');
        imgInfo.className = 'infoLivro';

        imgInfo.src = "Images/info.png";

        divLivro.appendChild(imgInfo);
```

Comment: Amigo, a constante `infoLivro` está `null`. Verifica de onde vem o valor que estás tentando buscar para resolver o problema.

Comment: "Fiz uns testes, e quando eu já deixo essa div pré feita no html, o modal funciona, sendo exatamente o mesmo código que o js gera ao clicar no botão.". Você provavelmente está mandando monitorar o evento `click` antes de ter o elemento na página, já que ele é criado via javascript.

Comment: Olá @Benilson, acho que o problema não é o momento do monitoramento, pois, além de somente funcionar com a div criada no html quando fui testar. Eu fiz outro teste para o código rodar somente depois da div ser criada pelo js, mas continua com o mesmo erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está 100% correto na sua analise e pra resolver isso você vai precisar modificar o seu código, e eu não recomendo usar o `addEventListener()` para resolver esse problema é melhor que você use o evento `onclick` do `elemento`.
Isso porque o `addEventListener()` é cumulativo e se usar ele pode ser que a sua `função` execute mais de uma vez.

logo pra resolver o seu problema, você precisa adicionar a função desejada no evento onclick do elemento sempre que o elemento for criado, seu código deve ficar +/- assim:

```
let imgInfo = document.createElement('img');
    imgInfo.className = 'infoLivro';
    imgInfo.src = "Images/info.png";
    imgInfo.onclick = () => abreModalInfo('modalInfoLivro'));

    divLivro.appendChild(imgInfo);
```

Espero ter ajudado.